# How to create widget with QDateEdit

Tags: c++, qt, widget

According to my understanding of QDateEdit's API documentation it creates a widget for editing dates. The only public members it has are constructors. So I basically created a QT widgets application using the QT creator and have added the following code.

```
QTextStream cout(stdout);
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDate d1(2002,4,1)

    QDateEdit dateEdit(d1,0);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Even though no error is given no widget/window appears either. What am I not getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

call the show method

```
dateEdit.show();
```

this is required because QDateEdit  is a widget, and is not going to be displayed by default...

just do:

```
QDateEdit dateEdit(d1,0);
dateEdit.show();
```

---

## edit:

to your comment, additional question;

> Why doesn't a line like QString = InputDialog::getText(....) require the .show()

well the function getText is calling that internally:

documentation:
https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qdialog.html#exec

> int QDialog::exec()
>
> Shows the dialog as a modal dialog, blocking until the user closes it.
>   The function returns a DialogCode result.
>
> If the dialog is application modal, users cannot interact with any
>   other window in the same application until they close the dialog. If
>   the dialog is window modal, only interaction with the parent window is
>   blocked while the dialog is open. By default, the dialog is
>   application modal.
>
> See also open(), show(), result(), and setWindowModality().

source code:

```
QString QInputDialog::getText(QWidget *parent, const QString &title, const QString &label,
                              QLineEdit::EchoMode mode, const QString &text, bool *ok,
                              Qt::WindowFlags flags, Qt::InputMethodHints inputMethodHints)
{
    QAutoPointer<QInputDialog> dialog(new QInputDialog(parent, flags));
    dialog->setWindowTitle(title);
    dialog->setLabelText(label);
    dialog->setTextValue(text);
    dialog->setTextEchoMode(mode);
    dialog->setInputMethodHints(inputMethodHints);
    const int ret = dialog->exec();  // <== here!!!!
    if (ok)
        *ok = !!ret;
    if (ret) {
        return dialog->textValue();
    } else {
        return QString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why doesn't a line like QString = InputDialog::getText(....) require the .show() function in order for it to display but QDateEdit does?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDate>
#include <QDateEdit>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QDate d1(2002,4,1);

    QDateEdit dateEdit(d1,0);
    dateEdit.show(); // Call show()

    return a.exec(); // Run events loop
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Why doesn't a line like QString = InputDialog::getText(....) require the .show() function in order for it to display but QDateEdit does?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the widget but you are not calling the proper method to display it. In Qt, there is a dedicated method for that [`QWidget::show()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#show).  According to the docs, this method:

> Shows the widget and its child widgets.

As an alternative, you can call `showFullScreen`, `showMaximized`, or `setVisible(true)`.

So, try:

```
QDate d1(2002,4,1);
QDateEdit dateEdit(d1,0);
dateEdit.show();
```

Comment: Thanks. Why doesn't a line like QString = InputDialog::getText(....) require the .show() function in order for it to display but QDateEdit does?